# generate only birt chart in strut2 application in netbeans

Tags: java, charts, struts2, birt

I want to use Birt chart in my struts2 application in netbeans I had search it  but not found suitable link to understand how to implement in strut2 . I want to generate charts by giving dynanic input and display chart on on my webpage.

any on knows please help me.

Thanks

Comment: There is a Jasper plugin to produce reports. This is not Business Intelligence and Reporting Tools (BIRT) but if you can use it just for the chart production. If you check the struts2 plugins if I remember there was an other chart plugin. Try using one of those to produce charts and then refine your question with specifics as to how this differs from what you need (or maybe you'll find one of these works for you).

Comment: BTW the other plugin is for JFreeChart

Comment: If you self answer I am likely to upvote the answer as it supports the community.

Answer (score 0):

So for this problem I want to pass bean to chart design . I generate design in eclipse with all possible things that I want with selecting script  type as input source to graph and the saved chart design file copied into my WEB-INF folder with creating new folder for design.

add all dependencies jar file.

call as per following links

http://birtworld.blogspot.in/2010/02/birt-and-struts-2.html